# How do I use FOREACH when constructing XML data?

Tags: php, loops, foreach

I am creating XML data that creates a list of phone numbers that will be passed to an API.  I have constructed a "hardcoded" XML structure that works.

```
$data = <<<DATA
                <Order>
                <CustomerOrderId>1234567890</CustomerOrderId>
                <Name>Test</Name>
                <ExistingTelephoneNumberOrderType>
                    <TelephoneNumberList>
                        <TelephoneNumber>1234567890</TelephoneNumber>
                        <TelephoneNumber>1234567891</TelephoneNumber>
                        <TelephoneNumber>1234567892</TelephoneNumber>
                        <TelephoneNumber>1234567893</TelephoneNumber>
                    </TelephoneNumberList>
                </ExistingTelephoneNumberOrderType>
                <SiteId>0001</SiteId>                      
            </Order> 
DATA;
```

... But now need to add multiple entries getting the list of phone numbers from an array.

```
$phone_numbers = array("1234567890", "1234567891", "1234567892", "1234567893");
$data = <<<DATA
                <Order>
                <CustomerOrderId>1234567890</CustomerOrderId>
                <Name>Test</Name>
                <ExistingTelephoneNumberOrderType>
                    <TelephoneNumberList>

                       //this is where i need the foreach data looped
                        foreach($phone_numbers as $value){
                        echo '<TelephoneNumber>' . $value . '</TelephoneNumber>';
                        }

                    </TelephoneNumberList>
                </ExistingTelephoneNumberOrderType>
                <SiteId>0001</SiteId>                      
            </Order>
DATA;
```

Comment: What programming language is that?

Comment: Always include a language tag on your questions, that will ensure they reach the widest possible audience

Comment: Sorry about that.  I'm a newbie.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is essentially correct; you just need to break your XML data in the middle and then add the phone numbers to it in the `foreach` loop before outputting the rest of the XML:

```php
$phone_numbers = array("1234567890", "1234567891", "1234567892", "1234567893");
$data = <<<DATA
<Order>
    <CustomerOrderId>1234567890</CustomerOrderId>
    <Name>Test</Name>
    <ExistingTelephoneNumberOrderType>
        <TelephoneNumberList>

DATA;
foreach($phone_numbers as $value){
    $data .= "\t    <TelephoneNumber>$value</TelephoneNumber>\n";
}
$data .= <<<DATA
        </TelephoneNumberList>
    </ExistingTelephoneNumberOrderType>
    <SiteId>0001</SiteId>                      
</Order>
DATA;
echo $data;
```

Output:

```xml
<Order>
    <CustomerOrderId>1234567890</CustomerOrderId>
    <Name>Test</Name>
    <ExistingTelephoneNumberOrderType>
        <TelephoneNumberList>
            <TelephoneNumber>1234567890</TelephoneNumber>
            <TelephoneNumber>1234567891</TelephoneNumber>
            <TelephoneNumber>1234567892</TelephoneNumber>
            <TelephoneNumber>1234567893</TelephoneNumber>
        </TelephoneNumberList>
    </ExistingTelephoneNumberOrderType>
    <SiteId>0001</SiteId>                      
</Order>
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/GLMkn)